# Flutter - spinning wheel

Tags: flutter

Im trying to build this kind of spinning wheel. is there any plugin or widget that can help to achieve this?

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjDX6.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ListWheelScrollView class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html)

List Wheel scroll view class will solve your problem